# Eliminate gap between lines of text

Tags: css, text

When you increase the line-height of an element, you start getting gaps between each line of text. Most of the time this is fine, since you don't see the specific gap.

But it is problematic when you have a narrow column, with a link that runs over multiple lines. If you move your mouse over the link, there is a small gap between the lines, which makes the link hover effect flash on and off.

From a design/usability perspective, I feel this makes for a bad user experience (no one likes random flashing). Try it with this:

> [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In est. Nunc aliquam, eros a aliquam consequat, ante diam rutrum risus, et dignissim ligula turpis et ante. Maecenas leo neque, euismod in, aliquam et, molestie ac, ligula. Integer venenatis. Pellentesque enim. Maecenas aliquet, tortor at molestie sodales, urna velit pulvinar lorem, ac malesuada nibh turpis eu tortor.](http://stackoverflow.com)

I can add some padding to links to prevent this happening in some cases, but it doesn't work when text is larger; I need more padding. Anyone have ideas for solutions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "but it doesn't work when text is larger; I need more padding"? Can you provide an example? Doesn't using relative units for the padding fix that?

Comment: You can probably try it using Firebug with the link above (now fixed). If you add a background to the link, you'll see the gap. Now increase padding, the gap disappears. Now increase the font size, the gap appears again. So the padding works sometimes but is not reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try fixing your flashing problem by setting display:block for your `<a>` element in that narrow column.

Comment: Not a terrible solution. The problem in this case is that the hover effect appears when the mouse is in the "generated box" but not actually over the link (i.e. to the right of the line).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the start and end point of each line you could put a span round each line, and turn it into an inline block

```
#wrap {font-size:14px; line-height:16px;}
a span{display:-moz-inline-block; display:inline-block;line-height:14px;padding:1px 0;}
a:hover {background:red;}

<div id="wrap">
dsvlaksvh; asvj asdfh;dhldv hd d dl h dfhd d dfh; daljfda k;d <a href="#" >
<span>hdv </span><span>dvh ldvhldf dhk </span><span>;dhkdf hdl hdfk 
</span><span>dfhkldf h vkhg j</span></a> glj gj f gjl fjl fj f
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is deliberate, but in your a span {} wouldn't the second display: inline-block overrule the -moz-inline-block?

Comment: yes it would. it's in that order because ffx 2 doesn't support inline-block, so you need the hack, but ffx 3 does support it, so putting inline-block last makes sure it is applied

Answer (score 0):

Use relative units to set the padding.

Adding `padding: 0.2ex 0; background: red;` using Firebug/Dragonfly to the example link in the question works just fine for me, whatever the font size (set through CSS or zooming in).

The only problem with changing the font-size in Firefox is that the background starts overlapping the previous line; but that's a `line-height` issue.